# Where to find notarytool?

Tags: xcode, macos, notarization

I'm trying to sign and notarize my macOS application. The Apple developer documentation says to do `xcrun notarytool ...` per
[Customizing the notarization workflow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow).

But when I try this, I get an error xcrun:

> error: unable to find utility "notarytool", not a developer tool or in PATH.

The apple documentation simply says 'install Xcode 13 beta' and you'll have it. Well, I have Xcode 13 installed on macOS 11.6, do I have to downgrade to the beta? Reinstall? Look for it somewhere? Inside Xcode.app?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following to reset the tools path:

```
sudo xcode-select -r
```

Comment: Didn't fix anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use xcrun:

`xcrun notarytool ...`

[The Apple documentation was also updated to fix this at some point, but the developer video was not.]